# android toolbar no longer works

Tags: java, android, toolbar

so my friend "helped" me with my program a little only that his help brought more problems than actual help. I used to have a toolbar within one of my activities and while the rest of the code works, if the toolbar is present the program always stops. Getting no errors whatsoever. How to fix this?

The code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

public class ProjectCreateScreen extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.secondary_layout1);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.AwesomeBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rl">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:id="@+id/AwesomeBar"
        android:background="@color/custom_white">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</RelativeLayout>
```

There's a lot more code than i posted here but I removed it since everything except this part works.

Comment: can you post the Logcat output? I am not seeing any problems with the code as is... You say no errors happen but the app wouldn't crash without saying something about what caused the crash. Maybe you post the gradle dependencies?? Or the usage of the toolbar anywhere in your code

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is as you commented above:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead

This means you are not disabling Android's default action bar supplied by the activity and it's theme. Go into your styles.xml file and to the theme you activity is using (or application is using if all activities use the same theme) and do the following (example):

```
<style name="AppThemeToolbar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
     ...
     ...
</style>
```

**android:windowActionBar** set to false will disable the default action bar and your activities using a custom toolbar/actionbar will now no longer crash.

Comment: did it, still stops though :(

Comment: link the theme you are using. and try my edit by having the theme's parent be that.. I supplied an example with a theme that has an action bar. Create a new theme and set the theme in the AndroidManifest, or extend current theme for your activity to have it's parent be one with NoActionbar at the end (light vs. dark) seen in me answer.

Comment: setting it to .NoActionBar helped. Thank you :)